# Is this Charles theorem? $\vec {AC}=\vec{AB}+\vec{BC}$?

Tags: vectors

When I was in high school our math teacher said, this is Charles theorem:
$\vec {AC}=\vec{AB}+\vec{BC} $,  for A, B, and C located on an arbitrary line.
I searched in google and could not find the name of Charles associated with this.
Is there any special name for this theorem?

Comment: I think your teacher said it was *Chasles* theorem (or rather *Chasles' relation), named after the 19th century French mathematician Michel Chasles.

Comment: You are correct Bernard. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is Chasles theorem according to the following reference:
[image]